# I'm copying content of source file to target file by erasing the content of target file

Tags: python

But I'm getting ( AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'turncate')

### This is my code

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "This script erases the cotent of target file and replaces it with the content of source file."
print "Press RETURN to continue or CTRL+C to abort."

print "copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

source = open(from_file)
source_read = source.read()

print "Does the output file exists? %r" % exists(to_file)
print "Erasing the content of %s..." % (to_file)

target = open(to_file, 'w')
target.turncate()

print "Writing content of source file to target file.Please wait..."

target.write(source_read)

print "It's done, script credits Deepak H S"

target.close()
source.close()
```

---

### Error I'm getting

```
:~/pystuff$ python ex15.py new.txt test.txt
This script erases the cotent of target file and replaces it with the content of source file.
Press RETURN to continue or CTRL+C to abort.
copying from new.txt to test.txt
Does the output file exists? True
Erasing the content of test.txt...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex15.py", line 18, in <module>
    target.turncate()
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'turncate'
```

---

Plese help me on this issue.Thank you in advance.

Comment: `turncate` ? seriously? why do you want to turn Kate ?

Comment: `target.truncate()` @Jean-FrançoisFabre Not sure if they caught on to that

Comment: @ZachSchulze it's a typo but most of all: the call is not even needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual function name is `truncate` not `turncate` ! (any half-decent Python code editor auto-completes it)

Anyway, to make a constructive answer: when you do:

```
target = open(to_file, 'w')
```

you already truncate the file (set it to 0-size) because of the `w` mode. So there's no need for `truncate`, `turncate` or whatever. The job is already done.

Comment: @Deepak then you can consider accepting the answer.